# Probability of correct classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, graphical-model, model-evaluation

I am studying this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0478.pdf, in which the authors propose a method to predict the graph structure of a graphical model.

In the "Simulations" paragraph, they plot what they call "Probability of correct graph recovery vs. rescaled sample size. [...] Curves are based on average performance over 500 trials."
[image: Article plot]

Now, how is this "probability" defined? If I try to compute it simply as the ratio of correctly (with no error at all) recovered graphs over the number of all trials, I don't get results as good as shown in the pictures.
Plus, this way of measuring the performance of a classifier seems quite pessimistic to me, as it would not distinguish 90% accuracy from 10% accuracy, but only 100% from <100%.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: That seems to be the case, however, since the paper doesn't describe any other success metric. Are you looking at their raw data or generating your own? In the latter case, are you using the same toy problem(s)?

Comment: I am generating my own, trying to obtain the last plot (that is, the chain graph; it is the easiest and for now I'm trying to save on computation).
Yet I almost never reach 100% accuracy, even for big values of n (where I get ~90%).